# Выражение "шапочный разбор"

Tags: фразеология

Почему разбор именно шапочный?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Означает оно: прийти к тому моменту, когда все уже закончилось или заканчивается. А при чем тут разбор шапок? Оказывается, возникновение этого фразеологизма напрямую связано с религией, точнее с церковью и церковными канонами. Как известно, православная традиция запрещает мужчинам находиться в храме с покрытой головой. Зимой же все ходят в шапках, и при входе в храм мужчины были обязаны шапки снимать. Чтобы не держать головной убор в руках во время долгой, например, воскресной службы,  шапки складывали при входе в церковь в специально отведенном месте. По окончании службы, покидая церковь, прихожане разбирали свои шапки и выходили, надевая шапки уже на улице. 
Если же человек приходил к самому концу богослужения, когда все уже закончилось, то он заставал не службу, а собственно процесс разбора своих шапок верующими на выходе из церкви. Вот отсюда и пошло выражение к шапочному разбору , то есть к самому концу, когда все уже закончилось.

Answer (score 11):

«Шапочный разбор» - это  русское выражение. Связано оно с церковными обычаями: в церковь в головном уборе входить было нельзя. Приходя на церковную службу, прихожане оставляли головные уборы у входа. Когда служба заканчивалась, они разбирали свои шапки. То есть *пришёл к шапочному разбору* - очень сильно опоздал, все пропустил, пришел к самому концу.

Answer (score -1):

Шапочный разбор и шапочное знакомство произошли из истории выбора невестами женихов в Крыму во время его заселения при Екатерине 11. Солдаты после службы должны были оставаться в Крыму. Невест для них князь Потёмкин скупал по всей Руси по дешевки. Видимо не все были красавицами. И солдаты несмотря на свой возраст (45 лет)не хотели брать их в жены. Екатерина предложила невестам самим выбирать женихов по шапкам. Т.е. Только шапку она могла видеть. После свою шапку узнавал солдат и знакомство осуществлялось. Нравится не нравится выбор произошёл. Опоздать к шапочному разбору означает пропустить возможность выйти замуж по собственному выбору. Женихов нет, шапки разобраны. Поэтому это фразу не всегда правильно употребляют.

Comment: Если это авторская версия, то желательно указать это в тексте ответа. Если можно сослаться на источник, то желательно добавить ссылку.